# Fastest method to enumerate the child controls in a CDialog

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, cdialog

What's the best way to list all the controls that may be on a CDialog based form? The only method I've seen so far is `EnumChildWindows()` but this involves call backs. Is there no faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback will hardly affect the performance. What can affect the performance is your code within the callback. I think you can use EnumChildWindows without any issues.

Comment: Do you reckon that's faster than say GetNextWindow?

Comment: Yep, I think this is the quickest way. Using GetTickCount for some very basic time tests on dialogs with 35 items it's not even registering.